# DB2 Stored Procedure Returning SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, db2

I am currently using RazorSQL to test queries with IBM DB2. Right now, I am stuck on an issue with creating procedures

I have the following procedure. I create this procedure as an admin user called `db2inst1`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CANCEL_ACTIVITY (IN application_handle INTEGER)
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE UOW_ID INTEGER;
  DECLARE ACTIVITY_ID  INTEGER;

  FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT UOW_ID, ACTIVITY_ID FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.MON_GET_ACTIVITY(application_handle, -1))
  DO
    CALL WLM_CANCEL_ACTIVITY(application_handle, v.uow_id, v.activity_id);
  END FOR ;
END
```

Now, I log onto my regular user called `applicationtest` which is NOT an admin. If I run the following:

```
CALL CANCEL_ACTIVITY(12345)
```

I get the following error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=CANCEL_ACTIVITY;PROCEDURE, DRIVER=4.16.53
```

According to [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n440.html), it's caused by:

> NO AUTHORIZED routine-type BY THE NAME routine-name HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367803/db2-java-stored-procedure-call-return-error-sqlcode-440-sqlstate-42884), I ran this debug code to check if the users are the same, and it does not appear to be the same, because the results are:

```
  | ROUTINESCHEMA
1 | db2inst1
2 | DB2INST1
```

Logically, `ROUTINESCHEMA` should have my regular user `applicationtest` in it, right?

I even ran the following:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE CANCEL_ACTIVITY TO PUBLIC;
```

To see if it would help, but still, same error.

I also tried to create the procedure using `applicationtest`, but as expected, I don't have the privileges required to do so.

EDIT:

I just specified DB2INST1.CANCEL_PROCEDURE(12345), and now I am getting the following error:

```
2016-11-18 11:27:34.983 -0800 [ERROR|01c56|] :: Java::ComIbmDb2JccAm::SqlSyntaxErrorException : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=APPLICATIONTEST;EXECUTE;DB2INST1.CANCEL_ACTIVITY, DRIVER=4.16.53
```

I guess that user `applicationtest` doesn’t have permission to execute that procedure?

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to not have to call DB2INST1 before calling the procedure? So I can just call it like this `CALL CANCEL_PROCEDURE(..)` instead of `CALL DB2INST1.CANCEL_ACTIVITY`. I feel like this would remove a lot of the ambiguity..
2. How do I grant `applicationtest` the necessary privilege to call the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here:

1. The schema of the stored procedure is the implicit schema of the user that created the procedure. In this case the schema name is 'db2inst1'. When you connect with the other user, 'applicationtest' the implicit schema is the same name of the user. Then you have the following possibilities:

   - Set the schema to db2inst1: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html
   - Call the stored procedure with schema.name: db2inst1.cancel_activity
   - Set the path, including db2inst1 on it: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001014.html

   Between, the previous three options, I personally recommend the second one schema.name.

   2. The other problem is the execution permission. When you create a procedure, you have to grant execution to other users / groups. In this case, db2inst1 user created the procedure, but just this user (or someone with DBADM authority) can execute it.

Because you are connecting with the other user you have to grant the execution (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007699.html):

```
db2 grant execution on procedure db2inst1.cancel_activity to user applicationtest
```

Comment: Hi @angoca! Thank you -- if I set the current path, is that only for the current session and current user, or is it set globally? In the future, will I be able to just call `CALL CANCEL_ACTIVITY()` from then on?

Comment: The scope of the set path is for the current session. Each time you connect to the databases, you will need to change that register.

Comment: Calling the stored procedure with schema.name solved my issue. Thx